# Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top of the list?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer

#### Stack Exchange staff have announced an upcoming change to the way answer acceptance works.

- [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369569)

Currently, the original poster of a question can accept one non-deleted answer. This does several things,

- the question poster receives 2 rep, and the answer poster receives 15 rep
- the answer has an added green tick mark below its score and vote buttons
- the answer itself is pinned to the top of the list of answers, regardless of sort variable

This change will affect the last of these behaviors, removing the "pin to top".

The staff has indicated this may be configurable per site - each individual site can have this behavior turned off or left on (with the default setting yet to be determined by consensus and research).

### Please indicate by voting on the answers below, which setting you would prefer.

Downvotes will be ignored for this purpose, as they add no useful information. Just upvote one, or both or neither.

### Links

- Announcement - [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369569)
- post with links to user script which may "fix" behavior - [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/259155)
- Half of the text is stolen from a different place with a [permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369589/259155)
- [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/pets/query/1460870/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer), taken/forked from [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/11784), credits - created by Nihar Karve & Emilio Pisanty from Physics.SE

In our case, **it affects 114 questions out of 7,614 questions total**.

The consensus is that **we want to unpin the accepted answer** with 5* votes for and 2 votes against it. (* I'm counting my own opinion as a vote since the system wouldn't let me upvote an answer I created.)

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, unpin the accepted answer

The accepted answer shouldn't get special treatment; it should be sorted as it would have been if it hadn't been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

### No, keep the accepted answer pinned

Keep things the way they are; it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your patience in getting this change enacted here. I've changed the site setting for the Main Pets site for you as of just now. If at some point in the future you want to go back to pinning accepted answers, please start a new meta discussion about it and flag it for our attention with the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag.

I've only changed this on the main site, not on meta as well - most sites have only wanted to change this on main. If you'd like to also unpin accepted answers on meta, please let us know.